# FreeBSD 9 Sound Driver

Tags: freebsd, drivers, audio

I installed FreeBSD 9. I'm trying to make a sound to work but no luck.

My Sound Card: `Realtek ALC898`

Can someone help me how to make it to work (I'm creating custom kernel)?

Base on FreeBSD handbook I `kldload snd_driver` and I got:

`ppc0: cannot reserve I/O port range`

and `cat /dev/sndstat`:

```
pcm0: <HDA NVidia (Unknown) PCM #0 DisplayPort> (play)
pcm1: <HDA NVidia (Unknown) PCM #0 DisplayPort> (play)
pcm2: <HDA NVidia (Unknown) PCM #0 DisplayPort> (play)
pcm3: <HDA NVidia (Unknown) PCM #0 DisplayPort> (play)
pcm4: <HDA Realtek (Unknown) PCM #0 Analog> (play/rec) default
pcm5: <HDA Realtek (Unknown) PCM #1 Digital> (play)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `cat /random >/dev/dsp` from terminal and if you can header static this means that your sound card recognized by FreeBSD and the driver loaded successfully.

Also in your `/boot/loader.conf` make sure `hint.hdac.1.cad0.nid17.config="as=6"` is exists or set in your BIOS. Without that your internal S/PDIF out and rear analog inputs won't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what program you're using to test, make sure that the output is set to pcm4/5.  It's possible that it's trying to output the audio over the HDMI connection on your video card.  The first 3 entries are audio on the video card.  You can also check to see if the volume is set high enough.

Answer (score 0):

The ppc0 line has nothing to do with your soundcard, it is about probing your parallel port.

The output from /dev/sndstat suggests that your soundcard is recognized as pcm4 or pcm5.
How did you test, that it does not work?